# Django выдаёт ошибку когда я выполняю items = order.orderitem_set.all()) данную операцию

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

При обращение просто к queryset'у он всё выводит, если я обращаюсь к orderitem - выводит ошибку

Traceback
Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/cart/

Django Version: 3.1.5
Python Version: 3.7.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'store.apps.StoreConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\glebt\Desktop\MyWorks\secondshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\glebt\Desktop\MyWorks\secondshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\glebt\Desktop\MyWorks\secondshop\shop\store\views.py", line 15, in cart
    items = order.orderitem_set.all()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /cart/
Exception Value: 'Order' object has no attribute 'orderitem_set'
```

**MODELS**

```
    class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url


class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_order = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class Order_item(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    qunatity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**VIEWS**

```
def store(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products': products}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()

    else:
        items = []
    context = {'items': items}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
    <div class="box-element">
        {% for item in items %}
        <div class="cart-row">
            <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.imageURL}}" alt=""></div>
            <div style="flex:2"><p>{{item.product.name}}</p></div>
            <div style="flex:1"><p>{{item.product.price|floatformat:2}}</p></div>
            <div style="flex:1"><p class="quantity">{{item.qunatity}}</p>

                <div class="quantity">
                    <img class="chg-quantity" src="{% static 'images/arrow-up.png' %}" alt="">
                    <img class="chg-quantity" src="{% static 'images/arrow-down.png' %}" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="flex:1"><p>$46</p></div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: трейс ошибки покажете?

Answer (score 1):

У вас модель `Order_item` следовательно вместо

```
items = order.orderitem_set.all()
```

надо писать

```
items = order.order_item_set.all()
```

Также советую для связанных моделей задавать поле `related_name`
т.е. например так.

```
order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
    blank=True, null=True, related_name='orderitem')
```

и тогда во `views` получить все объекты можно так

```
items = order.orderitem.all()
```